# About the deployment of website to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a website and deploy it on the IIS server. I want to change some code on the 
the default.aspx. After I change the code on my own computer. I copy the default.aspx and default.aspx.cs file to the server. But seems don't work on the server. But the website work perfectly on my own computer. I would like to ask do I need to copy files other than the default.aspx and default.aspx.cs? Thank you

Comment: What's the error and where is the code?

Comment: You might want to clear the asp.net cache on your server at this location `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<your framework version here>\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the [project type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx), you need to deploy the assembly into which the changes were compiled. If this is a web application, the web project should have a corresponding DLL.

Comment: My type is a website type.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a web site or a web application project in VS? It sounds from your brief description that it maybe a web application (code behind file) so once C# code has changed then you will need to compile it put the default.aspx and the newly compiled dll up on your hosting.

HTH

Comment: Then what file I should copy after compile?

Comment: The markup file (default.aspx) and the dll for the project which will be in the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

upload dll if you change code behind and aspx if you change design

load your page on browser,if nothing has change press "ctrl + f5" to clear cache and refresh your page

Comment: -1 - not true. While you *can* deploy locally, you can also copy pages, controls, assemblies, etc. from the source directory to a target server with no need to deploy locally as an intermediate step.

Comment: what! in source directory you see the cs file but when you deploy,they converted to dll file

Comment: The DLL(s) for the site are also created every time you compile or debug the application (not just when you deploy). You can copy directly from there if you so choose. If you remove the word "must", I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Still WRONG..!! No need to upload cs file, just upload the dll, its enough if any thing is changed in code nehind.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to compile your solution and put latest ***dll*** of the project containing `Default.aspx` file, in server's `bin` directory, since you have made changes to code behind file `Default.aspx.cs`.